# Why isn't my input key being removed from my dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, python-3.7

Just learning to code on Python so I created this test dictionary. 
I want the input to be removed from the dictionary, however every time I print the dictionary after the pop function it does not remove the key or value. 
I'm using this is Python 3.7.2 Shell

```
firstDict = {1:"five", 2:"ten", 3:"fifteen", 4:"twenty"}
print(firstDict)
inputKeyToDelete = input("Please enter a key whose corresponding value you wish to delete: ")
if inputKeyToDelete in firstDict:
    firstDict.pop(inputKeyToDelete)
print(firstDict)
```

If I input a key (2 for example) I'd like that key and value `(2:"ten")` to be removed from the dictionary
I expect the output to be:
`(1:"five", 3:"fifteen", 4:"twenty")`

Comment: because your keys in the dict are integers, but any user input is a string as default `2 != '2'`

Comment: String vs int. Use `int(input("Please enter a key for deletion: "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply convert the input string to an integer using `int()`.
Like so:

```
inputKeyToDelete = int(input("Please enter a key whose corresponding value you wish to delete: "))
```

That's because `input()` reads a **string** from standard input.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for clarifying!